# How to pass enum in Mutation using graphql in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

mutation{addOrder (create:{ offerId:2,paymentType:PaymentType!})
{
id
}
}

Here is my code .here PaymentType is a enum.

Comment: pass it as normal string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since you have the PaymentType you can use it normally , example:

```
PaymentType =enum {"visa" ,"masterCard"}
```

you have to passe the variable in you flutter end which corresponds to one of these two anyother value will generate an error
the variables should be something like this :

```
variables :{offerId:2,paymentType:"visa"}
```